# BlueJ, NetBeans, Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I just started with Java and downloaded Netbeans, i kind of like it, but i hear a lot about BlueJ and i was wondering wether if downloading and using BlueJ would be of any use when im happy with Netbeans .. or simply tell me if i am comparing two things that aren't comparable and should coexist :D thanks,
Samuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlueJ is geared towards teaching Java, whereas NetBeans will provide many more advanced features. If you're happy with NetBeans I would stick with it. BlueJ will be more limited in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Also try [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). It's the most popular IDE (and rightly so) for Java.

Comment: Also, try Intellij.  Its the best IDE (and rightly so) for Java. ;)

Comment: @jsight: LOL! Matter of personal taste! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I would recommend you to start with Eclipse. You could go from Netbeans to Eclipse, but I think starting from Eclipse is the best. By starting from Eclipse, you will be able to transition to "better" IDE's, such as InteliJ. But for learning, you are good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a practitioner you have to learn a lot of things unrelated to IDE's that are simply tools; if you don't have/want to spend/add time to deal with IDE's(and their relative learning curve; they're complicated beasts at times) then go with BlueJ, drJAva or similar tools